# lets-encrypt ssl certificate on local network

Tags: ssl, localhost, lets-encrypt

I have site where it can be accessed from web by domain name and also from local network by IP.

For sites that are only accessed from public network by domain name I use letsencrypt SSL ceriticate without any problem.

But when I want to access by local IP it's issuing errors. How can I install letsencrypt certificate for public domain and local IP at the same time?

Comment: You can’t, the Let’s Encrypt certificate is valid for the domain it was created under only. The easiest option would probably be to use the certificate for the domain anyway, and add an exception in your browser to accept this invalid certificate for when the site is accessed via the IP. Or to just use the domain name to access the site to begin with (I don’t see what actual benefit you get from using the IP to do this so far ...)

Comment: @CBroe it is accessed from local IP like 192.168.1.10 not public IP. Public access is done by domain.